# Не передаются данные в компонент Vue Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Пытаюсь передать данные в компонент, но почему то данная ошибка? expression expected. Подскажите пожалуйста кто знает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
<input    
    v-model="query"
    v-on:keyup="autoComplete"
    class="form-control js-region-name"
    name="regionName"
    value=""
>

export default{
        props: ['enteredRegion'],
        data(){
            return {
                query: '',                
            }
        },
        methods: {
            
        }
    }
```

```html
<autocomplete-region-component :enteredRegion="{{ old('regionName') }}"></autocomplete-region-component>
```

Comment: уберите все фигурные скобки

Comment: не помогло( там функция old шаблонизатора вызывается если убрать фигурные скобки то она не сработает и значение не передастся

Comment: Если используете Vue, забудьте о Blade. Передать данные так вы уже не сможете. Пишите в шаблоне скрипт снизу с данными и в него передавайте олды. Дальше уже в компоненте подхватывайте их.